# proper way to handle windows service error

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services, threadpool, semaphore

I'm building a multi-thread windows service. I'm having a little difficulty figuring out the best way to cleanly stop the service once all the threads have run through. The code is below. I have looked at ManualResetEvent, CountdownEvent and using Interlocked. I'm not sure which one would best suit my implementation.

Thanks for the assistance.

```
    private bool _isExiting;
    private bool IsExiting //if this is set to true exit but wait for all threads
    {
        get { return _isExiting; }
        set
        {
            _isExiting = value;
            if (value)
                Stop();
        }
    }
   private JobProfiler profiler;

   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            profiler = new Profiler(MaxThreads);
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoWork); // main thread set up thread for work
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogError(ex);
            Stop();
        }
    }

    protected void DoWork(object data)
    {
        while (!IsExiting)
        {
            try
            {
                profiler.RunProfiles(profiles); //this should wait until all child threads are done
                Thread.Sleep(ThreadSleep); //sleep before next iteration
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                LogError(ex);
                errorCount++;

                if (errorCount > 10)  //if 10 serious errors happen stop the service
                {
                    IsExiting = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        try
        {

            if(profiler != null)
                profiler.IsExiting = true; //setting a variable here to signal all remaining threads to stop

            //here it should be waiting for the main and child threads to finish

            base.OnStop();
        }
        catch
        {
            base.OnStop();
        }
    }


    //profiler class
    //******************************************************

    private readonly Semaphore _throttle;   //setting up a throttle for the number of threads we will allow to execute at once

    public void RunProfiles(List<Profiles> profiles)
    {
        foreach (var profile in profiles)
        {
            if (IsExiting) break; //if an exit command is called stop iterating

            _throttle.WaitOne(); // Wait on a semaphore slot to become available
            ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunProfile, profile ); //then add to thread queue

        }
    }

    private void RunProfile(object profile)
    {
        try
        {
            var p = (profile as Profile);

            if (p == null || IsExiting)
            {
                _throttle.Release(); // Release the semaphore slot if profile not found or if we're exiting
                return;
            }

            //****
            //do a bunch of stuff
            //****

            _throttle.Release(); // Release the semaphore slot

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            log.Error(ex);
            _throttle.Release(); // Release the semaphore slot
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use Tasks (TPL from .NET 4.0) and use CancellationToken to cancel tasks if Stop event occurs or some exception and you want to stop the service.

But if you want to stick to the semaphore or older synchronization primitives your solution will work just fine.

Also check out this article(s): [Threading](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx)

There are several useful examples in there that may help you to pick the best solution. I believe CountdownEvent is highly optimized and OS independent, so from your list, I would pick that one.